# Java: Why the need to type cast for instanceof() in equals()? Is it for reference or less code?

Tags: java, types, casting, equals, instanceof

Java newbie here, I have a basic question that is half answered by previous responses in other threads or the docs, but I still don't fully understand the mechanism and I want to be sure I covers the fundamentals (code at bottom, questions in middle).

Basically, I'm overriding the equals() method to check if two MyDate objects have the same date. I do an instanceof check if the o object is a MyDate object, then you type cast a temp object specifically to a MyDate object `o`, then you compare dates.  **Why do you type cast the temp variable to MyDate class of o, when it already is of the MyDate class?**

1. Do you use temp variable as an easier reference the object you want to run the equals() comparison? Because you use equals() as comparing `MyDate.equals(MyOtherDate)`, in the code if I don't designate a variable to hold the reference then you get various errors (temp cannot be resolved as a variable, type mismatch, etc basically the compiler isn't sure where to look unless you write a bunch more code).

2a. Some of the other threads said something to the effect that while instanceof checks if an instance is from a class, it checks the **base** class, but doesn't check a subclass. You do the typecasting because you're specifically telling the compiler to check for that specific object (type casting from a general object to a specific object). NOTE: This might be a version and flavor specific type question, I've seen different replies to similar questions.

2b. Casting changes the reference, not the object itself. So, if the objects are from the same class, but different subclasses, wouldn't it fail at runtime, instead of compile time. And wouldn't I get a ClassCastException?

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof MyDate) {
                MyDate temp = (MyDate) o;
                if ((temp.day == day) && (temp.month == month) && (temp.year == year)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Try removing the cast, using `o` directly, and see what happens.

Comment: `o` is an instance of `Object` - it's "something".  `instanceof` simple determines if it's "safe" to cast the given object to a given type.  You need to cast `o` to `MyDate` before you can interact with the functionality of the object, otherwise, it's still just an `Object`. *"You do the typecasting because you're specifically telling the compiler to check for that specific object"* - Ah, no.  This is not a check, this is an instruction, one which could cause a run time error if you cast it to an incompatible type

Comment: Yeah, that leads to more code (in response to remove o from the type casting). If I remove o the compiler doesn't know where to look for temp and I get a bunch of warning messages.

Comment: "*Casting changes the reference, not the object itself"* - Not sure I understand. The object is always it's own type.  It's stored in memory and you "reference" it via variables.  So, no.  Instead, you change the way you are "looking at" the reference.  You take off your `Object` glasses and put on your `MyDate` glasses

Comment: What you're looking at is polymorphism in action.  A instance of a class may be represented as it self or it's children (so `MyDate` can act as an `Object` because all objects in Java extend from `Object`)

Comment: Yes, mostly. ```o``` is an instance of "something", but I thought instanceof is a boolean operator that checks if an object is an instanceof a particular Class. Also, I thought I'm typecasting temp, = is an assignment operator, not typecasting ```o```. And good to know about the instructions vs a check. I kept thinking it was a check.

Comment: So for the "Casting changes the reference, not the object itself", what I mean by that is I'm telling the JVM where to look to access the data. As I understand object type casting, you take a general object type and cast it to a specific type. In the above code, I'm telling the JVM how to access the data. More generally, I can do a "bad" cast and will get an error, BUT at runtime, not compile time. The compiler will accept the change in references, but it doesn't change the object, so when it runs it doesn't find the properties/fields and get a bunch of errors.

Comment: "but I thought instanceof is a boolean operator that checks if an object is an instanceof a particular Class" – it is a boolean-returning operator, hence its use in the `if` condition. If the operator returns true then we know it's safe to perform the following casting operation.

Answer (score 2):

The Java compiler doesn't understand the type class of your object "o" as being MyDate. This happen because you've received a parameter of the type Object so it will be read as an object. In order to access the methods and properties of the parameter of known type MyDate, you need to tell the compiler that this is an object of type `MyDate`. This is the way the compiler is going to understand what you're doing. Now let's take a look to another view sight.

Every types in Java extends the type `Object` which means that every time you write a class, you're implicitly extending the `Object` public/protected properties and behaviors. That's why you are "overriding" the method `equals` that belongs to the `Object` type. Alright, when you're doing a comparison between two objects you must first check if both of them belongs to the same type, as you did in your example with: `if (o instanceof MyDate) { ... }` to ensure that `o` is of type `MyDate`. But at this point, as you didn't cast "o" to "MyDate" type you won't be able to access MyDate's specific properties or methods. So think of it for a while, if I have a class `A` that extends my class `B` I will be able to access B public methods and properties inside A, but I can't do the same on B because B can't see what's happening down the tree. Do you follow?

Hope I could answer your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Java has two related-but-separate concepts: the *type* of an *expression*, and the *runtime-type* of a *value*.

These concepts are compatible to some extent; if an expression has type `MyDate`, then when you evaluate that expression, you either get a reference to an object whose runtime-type is either `MyDate` or a subclass of `MyDate`, or you get a null reference, or you get an exception or infinite loop or whatnot. But the concepts are separate, and even when your runtime-types are fine, sometimes you need to give the compiler some extra information about the types.

> Why do you type cast the temp variable to MyDate class of o, when it already is of the MyDate class?

The variable `o` is of type `Object`, not *ever* of type `MyDate`. It happens to contain a reference to an object whose runtime-type is `MyDate` (or a subclass of `MyDate`), but that doesn't affect the type of `o`. So you write `(MyDate)o` to create an expression with the same value (and hence the same runtime-type) and the desired type.

If the compiler were smarter, it could perhaps treat `o` as having type `MyDate` inside your `if`-statement, so you wouldn't need the cast; but the current Java Language Specification doesn't allow that. (And if it did, that could have some weird implications when it comes to static method dispatch.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that and it makes a lot of sense. I kept thinking because Java is hard typed it should know the difference, but both are objects, so they are the same type, so no warnings and will pass at compile time. At runtime it will check references.

Comment: _If the compiler were smarter, it could perhaps treat o as having type MyDate inside your if-statement, so you wouldn't need the cast; but the current Java Language Specification doesn't allow that._ 

Note that Java 14 adds this: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305

Comment: @KartikChugh: Cool find, thanks! But it won't really affect this question or answer IMHO; it adds a new syntax that lets you declare `temp` without an explicit cast, but it doesn't change the meaning of the OP's code, and doesn't enable e.g. `MyDate temp = o`.

Comment: Yeah just a minor observation